# Integration Testing Spring Data Envers using Testcontainers and Spring Boot DataJpaTest

Tags: spring-boot, testcontainers, spring-data-envers

I recently integrated Envers (Spring Data Envers) into my microservice and I'd like to test it.

I'm able to get my test to spin up a Testcontainer (Postgresql), run the Flyway migrations to create the tables, and do inserts into the tables using a JPA repository that I autowire.

But when I attempt to get the Revisions from the Envers audit table, I get an error stating that the table does not exist.

I suspect this has something to do with how I've configured this test using `@DataJpaTest`.  `@DataJpaTest` disables a lot of functionality that would otherwise be present with `@SpringBootTest`, so that only JPA-related code is wired up.  I'd like to add Envers to this.  It's not clear to me what I need to do to get the Envers code to run and create the `_aud` tables.

My test class (Groovy/Spock):

```
@DataJpaTest
@Testcontainers
@AutoConfigureTestDatabase(replace = AutoConfigureTestDatabase.Replace.NONE)
@ActiveProfiles("tc")
class FooRepositoryITSpec extends Specification {

    @Autowired
    private FooRepository fooRepository

    void "test envers functionality"() {
        given:
        var foo = new Foo()

        when:
        fooRepository.save(foo)
        var revisions = fooRepository.findRevisions(foo.getId()) // ERROR HERE - org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: ERROR: relation "foo_aud" does not exist

        then:
        revisions.size() == 1
        var revision = revisions.collect().get(0)
        revision.getRevisionNumber() != null
    }
```

`application-tc.yaml` overrides the connection parameters to direct to the ephemeral Postgresql instance running in Docker, which is standard when using Testcontainers:

```
spring:
  datasource:
    url: jdbc:tc:postgresql:13:///test_database
    username: user
    password: password
    driver-class-name: org.testcontainers.jdbc.ContainerDatabaseDriver
```

Comment: which spring boot version are you using? hibernate version?

Comment: Have you tried running the test with `@SpringBootTest` instead?

Comment: How do your create the ```_aud``` tables for envers? Are the requried DDL statements included in your flyway scripts?